# jQuery Form Problems

Tags: jquery, forms

I am using a jQuery plugin. I need help with changing the type of form from a "create a user" form to a different type. [Here](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form) is the link to the original:  (view source towards the bottom)

Code I am struggling with

```
"Insert Purchase": function () {
  var bValid = true;
  allFields.removeClass("ui-state-error");
  bValid = bValid && checkRegexp(total_price, /([0-9])/, "total_price may consist of  0-9");
  bValid = bValid && checkRegexp(item_cost, /([0-9])/, "item_cost field only allow :  0-9");
  bValid = bValid && checkRegexp(tax, /([0-9])/, "tax field only allow :  0-9");
  if (bValid) {
    $("#users tbody").append("<tr>" +
      "<td>" + total_price.val() + "</td>" +
      "<td>" + item_cost.val() + "</td>" +
      "<td>" + tax.val() + "</td>" +
      "</tr>");
    $(this).dialog("close");
  }
},
Cancel: function () {
  $(this).dialog("close");
}
},
```

But more specifically, the middle section:

```
if(bvalid) ...... $(this).dialog ("close");
```

Comment: noone with this problem will ever find this question with the given title.

Comment: What does this have to do with Java? Why the Java tag?

Comment: eh, i dont think you understand how little i know what im doing... im using a jquery plugin called dialog so i figured it was java and im having trouble with the plugin so thats what i used as my title.

Answer (score 1):

bvalid is a boolean. If any of the regex expressions renders false, then bvalid is false.

in the if statement the bvalid is tested on its state

```
if( bvalid == true ) {

       // add the data to some table in the document
       // and close this dialog

     $(this).dialog ("close");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i think that helps. Also what can i do to make the total price, item cost and tax only accept numbers and periods, i think i have it correctly set up for numbers right now

Comment: You should look into the `parseFloat()` and the `toFixed(2)` to deal with number formatting. You may want to search for "number to currency conversion".